# Сравнение чисел в диапазоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Функция возвращает цвет пикселя в RGB формата [255, 255, 255]. На некоторых устройствах цвет почемуто разнится в диапазоне +1 -1. Пример:

```py
ПервоеУстройство = getRGBcolor(20, 34) # Вернуло [107, 182, 148]
ВтороеУстройство = getRGBcolor(20, 34) # Вернуло [107, 182, 149]
if getRGBcolor(20,34) == [107, 182, 148]:
    Делаем действия..
```

Редактировать на каждом устройстве цвет под нужный идея бредовая. Поэтому решил написать функцию которая вернет нам True если цифры находятся в диапазоне.

```py
def (colorInPos, checkColor): #getRGBcolor(20, 34), checkColor = [107, 182, 148]
    val1 = colorInPos[0] - checkColor[0]
    val2 = colorInPos[1] - checkColor[1]
    val3 = colorInPos[2] - checkColor[2]
    if val1 <= 3 and val2 <= 3 and val3 <=3:
        return True
```

И я решил что могу эту задачу решить отнимая числа друг от друга. Но выглядит это так себе.. Может есть метод покрасивее/получше?

Comment: Для начала, надо бы исправить баг, `val1 = abs(color - color)` — брать модуль, чтобы не получилось `-50 <= 3` ) А вместо `if ...: return True` можно сразу `return условие`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, можно сделать цикл вместо прямого сравнения 0, 1, 2. Тогда она научится сравнивать любые 2 массива чисел, не так важно - это цвет или что.

```
def nearly_equal(list_1, list_2):
    for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2):
        if abs(a - b) >= 3: return False
    return True
```

То же самое, с генератором + `any()`, который дает True только если все элементы переданного итерируемого объекта в логическом контексте будут True.

```
def nearly_equal(list_1, list_2, *, scatter = 2): # параметр - разброс.
    return all(abs(a - b) <= scatter for (a, b) in zip(list_1, list_2))


print( nearly_equal([7, 7, 7], [5, 9, 5]) ) # True
print( nearly_equal([7, 7, 7], [5, 9, 5], scatter = 1) ) # False
print( nearly_equal([7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8], scatter = 1) ) # True
```

Answer (score 2):

ну например можно сделать так. сумма разниц для всех блоков не должна превысить лимит.

```
color1 = [107, 182, 148]
color2 = [106, 183, 149]


def is_eq(a, b):
    return sum((abs(a-b) for a, b in zip(a, b))) < 4


print(is_eq(color1, color2))
```

в данном случае каждый блок разнится на +-1 что в сумме дадут 3. но тут есть подвох, один блок может отличаться на 3. тогда можно и по другому, например получить максимальную разницу max, которая должна быть не более 1

```
color1 = [107, 182, 148]
color2 = [106, 183, 149]


def is_eq(a, b):
    return max((abs(a-b) for a, b in zip(a, b))) < 2


print(is_eq(color1, color2))
```